# How to get gitlab CI to checkout my submodule?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

My application consists of a .NET C# WebApi backend and a npm/node/Javascript frontend.

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml script. Below is the gitlab CI configuration file. I have removed irrelevant text.

```
stages:
 - build
build-backend:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build-backend"
    - dotnet clean WebApiServer --configuration Release
    - dotnet build WebApiServer --configuration Release    
  artifacts:
    name: "Backend-${CI_JOB_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - WebApiServer/bin/Release  
build-frontend:
  image: node:12
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build-frontend"
    - git submodule init
    - git submodule update
    - cd WebApiServer/client
    - npm install
    - node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env=prod --progress --profile --config=webpack.prod.js  
  artifacts:
    name: "Frontend-${CI_JOB_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
    paths:
      - build
    expire_in: 1 day
```

The backend builds correctly.

But the frontend gives an error. It seems gitlab cannot checkout the submodule. Although the submodule is hosted on the same gitlab server as the backend.

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
Cloning into '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@git.company.ab:subcompany/clientname/WebApiServerclient.git' into submodule path '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client' failed
Failed to clone 'WebApiServer/client'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@git.company.ab:subcompany/clientname/WebApiServerclient.git' into submodule path '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client' failed
Failed to clone 'WebApiServer/client' a second time, aborting
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

.gitmodules

```
[submodule "WebApiServer/client"]
    path = WebApiServer/client
    url = git@git.company.ab:subcompany/clientcompany/client.git
    branch = development
```

Questions

1. How to get gitlab to checkout the submodule?
2. In gitmodules should I use the SSH type URL or the HTTPS type URL?

---

**Update**

I did try `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive`. I would prefer not to use `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive`.

The error message when using `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive`

```
Synchronizing submodule url for 'WebApiServer/client'
17Cloning into '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client'...
18error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
19fatal: unable to fork
20fatal: clone of 'git@git.company.ab:subcompany/clientname/client.git' into submodule path '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client' failed
21Failed to clone 'WebApiServer/client'. Retry scheduled
22Cloning into '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client'...
23error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
24fatal: unable to fork
25fatal: clone of 'git@git.company.ab:subcompany/clientname/client.git' into submodule path '/builds/subcompany/clientname/WebApiServer/WebApiServer/client' failed
26Failed to clone 'WebApiServer/client' a second time, aborting
28ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1.
```

Comment: sooo https://www.google.com/search?q=gitlab+CI+to+checkout+my+submodule what research did you do? There is like a whole page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html of documentation.... `In gitmodules should I use the SSH type URL or the HTTPS type URL?` Neither, use relative paths when possible. Otherwise does not matter.

Comment: I have read the gitlab documentation. I have also tried various keys (deploy and token), relative paths. Nothing seems to work. I have tried to keep the question as simply as possible.

Comment: If you did read it, then why is there no `variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY:` in your configuration?? The [points](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#using-git-submodules-in-your-ci-jobs) are pretty clear: 1. First, make sure you have used relative URLs for the submodules located in the same GitLab server 2. you can set the GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY variable to either normal or recursive. ? ` have also tried various keys (deploy and token)`  Adding ssh keys is [also documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/)

Comment: Yes tried all of that. I've updated my question. No matter what combination I try, I get the 2 error messages in the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting `variables.GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY`, and using a relative URL in your `.gitmodules` file, something like:

```
[submodule "WebApiServer/client"]
path = WebApiServer/client
url = ../client.git
```

You also need to enable Token Access in the submodule's Project configuration:

```
Settings > CI/CD Settings > Token Access
```

Ensure "Allow access to this project with a CI_JOB_TOKEN" is enabled, and add your parent project's path to the field below "Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project" and click "Add project".

This will ensure that your parent project has permission to clone the submodule repository.